# iOS Camera Customization: How to implement Grid Lines?

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I am able to use the flash feature, access the photo gallery, and use the rear/front camera.

I would like to implement grid lines that display when the user is taking a photo.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a `UIImageView` to use for the `cameraOverlayView`.

Assuming you've got a `UIImagePickerController` named `yourImagePickerController` and also that you've got an image file named `overlay.png` as your 'grid lines'.  When making your grid line image file, be sure to use a transparent background - not opaque white.

```
UIImageView *overlayImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"overlay.png"]];

CGRect overlayRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, overlayImage.image.size.width, overlayImage.image.size.height);

[overlayImage setFrame:overlayRect];

[yourImagePickerController setCameraOverlayView:overlayImage];
```

Comment: Thank You rog. I have added four views with 1px height and 1px width accordingly on my overlay View. Now i Hide/show the same Programatically. Thanks For your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty easy with `UIBezierPath`. This is how you can achieve.

1. Save this code in a file called `GridView.swift`.

   ```
    import Foundation
    import UIKit

    class GridView: UIView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        let firstColumnPath = UIBezierPath()
        firstColumnPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width / 3, y: 0))
        firstColumnPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width / 3, y: bounds.height))
        let firstColumnLayer = gridLayer()
        firstColumnLayer.path = firstColumnPath.cgPath
        layer.addSublayer(firstColumnLayer)

        let secondColumnPath = UIBezierPath()
        secondColumnPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: (2 * bounds.width) / 3, y: 0))
        secondColumnPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (2 * bounds.width) / 3, y: bounds.height))
        let secondColumnLayer = gridLayer()
        secondColumnLayer.path = secondColumnPath.cgPath
        layer.addSublayer(secondColumnLayer)

        let firstRowPath = UIBezierPath()
        firstRowPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: bounds.height / 3))
        firstRowPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width, y: bounds.height / 3))
        let firstRowLayer = gridLayer()
        firstRowLayer.path = firstRowPath.cgPath
        layer.addSublayer(firstRowLayer)

        let secondRowPath = UIBezierPath()
        secondRowPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: ( 2 * bounds.height) / 3))
        secondRowPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width, y: ( 2 * bounds.height) / 3))
        let secondRowLayer = gridLayer()
        secondRowLayer.path = secondRowPath.cgPath
        layer.addSublayer(secondRowLayer)
    }
    private func gridLayer() -> CAShapeLayer {
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.3).cgColor
        shapeLayer.frame = bounds
        shapeLayer.fillColor = nil
        return shapeLayer
    }
   }
   ```

2. Usage:

   ```
   func addGridView(cameraView: UIView) {
    let horizontalMargin = cameraView.bounds.size.width / 4
    let verticalMargin = cameraView.bounds.size.height / 4

    let gridView = GridView()
    gridView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cameraView.addSubview(gridView)
    gridView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    gridView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cameraView.leftAnchor, constant: horizontalMargin).isActive = true
    gridView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cameraView.rightAnchor, constant: -1 * horizontalMargin).isActive = true
    gridView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cameraView.topAnchor, constant: verticalMargin).isActive = true
    gridView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cameraView.bottomAnchor, constant: -1 * verticalMargin).isActive = true
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

As far as the documentation goes it doesn't state whether the grid lines provided by Apple is actually a shared method but as it's not mentioned I'd say not, but you can implement your own [with the cameraOverlayView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html).