# Grid Lines in UIImagePicker camera

Tags: ios, swift, camera, grid, uiimagepickercontroller

I am developing an app that uses UIImagePickerController to capture photos in my current app. I would like to display grid lines (like the original iOS camera app).

At the moment I am adding a custom view as an overlay over my camera preview to draw the grid but the problem is I can’t never get it to be perfectly positioned on all devices. It’s a lot of manual math and guessing what position works on each of devices. 
I am wondering is there any better solution than what I am doing.

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS Camera Customization: How to implement Grid Lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15550080/ios-camera-customization-how-to-implement-grid-lines)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it doesn't quite help me. I am already using cameraOverlayView to display grid lines and it works, but my problem is positioning it correctly. As the answer you provided states that the grid lines should start X: 0, Y: 0 which isn't the case. The camera has black space on top and bottom which deferes from phone to phone. I am trying to find out is there a way of always starting exactly where the camera preview begins.

Comment: Possible duplicate: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67982488/4427884